# How do I programmatically check whether an image (PNG, JPEG, or GIF) is corrupted?

Tags: php, python, image

Okay. So I have about 250,000 high resolution images. What I want to do is go through all of them and find ones that are corrupted. If you know what 4scrape is, then you know the nature of the images I.

Corrupted, to me, is the image is loaded into Firefox and it says

> `The image “such and such image” cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.`

Now, I could select all of my 250,000 images (~150gb) and drag-n-drop them into Firefox. That would be bad though, because I don't think Mozilla designed Firefox to open 250,000 tabs. No, I need a way to programmatically check whether an image is corrupted.

Does anyone know a PHP or Python library which can do something along these lines? Or an existing piece of software for Windows?

I have already removed obviously corrupted images (such as ones that are 0 bytes) but I'm about 99.9% sure that there are more diseased images floating around in my throng of a collection.

Comment: lol I read that as "diseased images floating around in my THONG collection" +1 for a good question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An easy way would be to try loading and verifying the files with PIL (Python Imaging Library).

```
from PIL import Image

v_image = Image.open(file)
v_image.verify()
```

Catch the exceptions...

From [the documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm):

**im.verify()**

*Attempts to determine if the file is broken, without actually decoding the image data. If this method finds any problems, it raises suitable exceptions. This method only works on a newly opened image; if the image has already been loaded, the result is undefined. Also, if you need to load the image after using this method, you must reopen the image file.*

Comment: This is working for some of the the corrupted images. The advantage of this method is it is very fast. Thanks ChristopheD!

Comment: This solution is so simple that I've wrapped it around a Python script to recursively checks for corrupt files. I'm posting here in the hope it helps anyone else: http://bitbucket.org/denilsonsa/small_scripts/src

Comment: @DenilsonSá If I edit line 32: `self.globs = ['*.jpg', '*.jpe', '*.jpeg']` in  jpeg_corrupt.py, to include `*.png` and `*.gif`, would the rest of the code work fine in verifying PNG and GIF images too?

Comment: @galacticninja: I don't know, I haven't tried with those image types. Why don't you try and report back the results? Even better you come back with a nice pull request. :)

Comment: The `verify()` method won't work with all img formats. A truncated JPG file (and some other formats) can still "pass" both `verify()` and `open()` without raising exceptions. If you really want to cover everything, you can try `show()` or even better: `load()`. These will raise an exception if it fails, mostly `OSError`.

Comment: As of this comment, the verify method only works on PNG images. And it won't even cover things like IDAT errors.

Comment: @maviz I've been working on a little general-purpose checking script (which grew out of some Python to glue `os.walk` to `unzip -t` and `unrar t`) and I can tell you that `Image.load()` won't catch all JPEG errors. In fact none of the solutions I've found (even JPEG-specific ones) will catch the example someone else posted at https://superuser.com/q/276154/48014 so I'm probably going to have to look into whether the green stripes are solid-color enough to be programmatically recognizable as being "not what a JPEG should produce".

Comment: @ssokolow Did you make any progress on that?

Comment: @Hashim I had to put image-related stuff beyond `Image.load()` on hold to work on more pressing projects.

Comment: Update: my script (mentioned in the second comment) has moved from bitbucket to GitHub: https://github.com/denilsonsa/small_scripts/blob/master/jpeg_corrupt.py

Answer (score 7):

i suggest you check out imagemagick for this: http://www.imagemagick.org/

there you have a tool called identify which you can either use in combination with a script/stdout or you can use the programming interface provided

Comment: What is your (or anyone's) opinion about GraphicsMagick which is supposed to be a more stable fork of ImageMagick?

Comment: never played around with it - but i will give it a try - thanks for the info

Comment: Note that identify looks at the header only, so it should be quick, but it's not a guarantee against a corrupt image.  Though I'm sure other bits of imagemagick can provide a more thorough check.

Comment: Then again, you're scrapping from 4chan, corrupt images is kind of half the point, isn't it?  (I kid)

Comment: therefromhere is right. I tried identify out and it doesn't catch known broken images. Thanks anyways!

Comment: As noted [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20170/how-can-i-use-imagemagicks-identify-command-in-a-script-to-tell-if-a-jpeg-file) there is a tool called `jpeginfo`. Running `jpeginfo -c <file>` worked for me.

Comment: @trobter Be aware that I tried `jpeginfo` on the image with the green corruption that was uploaded on https://superuser.com/q/276154/48014 and it didn't catch it. (But then I haven't found *anything* which catches that yet, so I may have to cook something new up.)

Answer (score 5):

In PHP, with [exif_imagetype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php):

```
if (exif_imagetype($filename) === false)
{
    unlink($filename); // image is corrupted
}
```

**EDIT**: Or you can try to fully load the image with [ImageCreateFromString()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php):

```
if (ImageCreateFromString(file_get_contents($filename)) === false)
{
    unlink($filename); // image is corrupted
}
```

> An image resource will be returned on
>   success. **FALSE is returned if** the
>   image type is unsupported, the data is
>   not in a recognized format, or **the
>   image is corrupt** and cannot be loaded.

Comment: That only reads the first few bytes looking for an image header, that's not going to be enough to confirm the image isn't corrupt.

Comment: (though it's better than nothing, and it'd be quick)

Comment: The advantage of this method is that it checks the entire image for corruption. It's slower, but it is more thorough. Thanks eyze!

Comment: I tried the second one, but I keep getting errors: "libpng warning: Ignoring bad adaptive filter type", "libpng warning: Extra compressed data", "libpng warning: Extra compression data", and so on that appear to be coming from the libpng c library rather than PHP when the image is corrupted. Anyone else run into this?

Comment: Note that `imagecreatefromstring()` will load many types of corrupted images just fine, you will just get a partial image. I tested this with truncated JPEG files. It will usually write an error message to stderr, which is likely to go unnoticed.

Answer (score 4):

If your exact requirements are that it show correctly *in FireFox* you may have a difficult time - the only way to be sure would be to link to the exact same image loading source code as FireFox.

Basic image corruption (file is incomplete) can be detected simply by trying to open the file using any number of image libraries.

However many images can fail to display simply because they stretch a part of the file format that the particular viewer you are using can't handle (GIF in particular has a lot of these edge cases, but you can find JPEG and the rare PNG file that can only be displayed in specific viewers). There are also some ugly JPEG edge cases where the file *appears* to be uncorrupted in viewer X, but in reality the file has been cut short and is only displaying correctly because very little information has been lost (FireFox can show some cut off JPEGs correctly [you get a grey bottom], but others result in FireFox seeming the load them half way and then display the error message instead of the partial image)

Answer (score 0):

You could use imagemagick if it is available:

if you want to do a whole folder

```
identify "./myfolder/*" >log.txt 2>&1
```

if you want to just check a file:

```
identify myfile.jpg
```

Comment: That doesn’t seem to work. Using the `-verbose` switch does catch *some* damaged pictures, but also **drastically** increase the time to process each file.

Comment: Depends on the corruption I guess? This will find pictures that are corrupted in the first few bytes (or wherever it identifies them as the image type). It is essentially the same as using the `exif_imagetype()` function in php

Comment: Unfortunately that’s not very useful. Corruption of the header/magic number is quite trivial. What’s needed is something that can check if the picture adheres to the specs of the format (which also has the side-effect of ferreting out stego pics).

Comment: Interesting that the accepted answer is "use `exif_imagetype()`"

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes people have to settle. `:-(`