# How do I determine if a gif is animated?

Tags: bash, gif, animated-gif

I have large number of files with .gif extension. I would like to move all animated gifs to another directory. How can I do this using linux shell?

Comment: Have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412529/how-do-i-programmatically-check-whether-a-gif-image-is-animated ? This may not be possibly just from the shell...

Comment: @TomMedley Everything is possible "just from the shell". (inb4 "then where's my `./cure4cancer.sh`")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically, if [identify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) returns more than one line for a GIF, it's likely animated because it contains more than one image.  You may get false positives, however.

Example use in shell:

```
for i in *.gif; do
  if [ `identify "$i" | wc -l` -gt 1 ] ; then
    echo move "$i"
  else
    echo dont move "$i"
  fi
done
```