# Detecting animated GIF on the fly using PHP/CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, gif, animated-gif

Is there any way to check if an image [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) returns an animated or not GIF?

I need to save image URLs and then show the images on my site, so I would like to allow GIF extension, but I need to avoid animated GIFs. Is it possible to detect that on the fly with out downloading the image?

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412529/how-do-i-programmatically-check-whether-a-gif-image-is-animated

Comment: @Yadheendran php and more specifically Codeigniter Framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this comment to the documentation for function *imagecreatefromgif*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php#104473) (on php.net). You still need to first download the image file even if you are just going to link to it later.

Comment: no way to do that on the fly? don't want to save nothing on server pls

Comment: @Badaboooooom - There's nothing wrong in using temporary files.

Comment: well true ! :) i'll make some tests then i'll accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think, [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) really will be your best chance:

```
identify -format %n  posible_animation.gif
```

Please check the forum post *[How to identify animated image format](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11988)* for more information.