# How to list out only either static or animated images in Android?

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I want to detect and display most recent images and it should be either animated or static images on user choice.
Also cannot depend on extentions.Because

- There would be absence of extention
- webp images could be animated or static with same extention (.webp)
- It could be wrong extentions

Is there way to identify whether images are animated (webp, gif, apng) or static (jpg, png, webp, etc)?

```
private static final String[] COLUMNS_OF_INTEREST = new String[]
{
        MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.WIDTH,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.HEIGHT,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED
};

public void printGifUri(Context context)
{
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("webp");
    String[] selectionArgsPdf = new String[]{ mimeType };

    Cursor gifCursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, COLUMNS_OF_INTEREST, selection,selectionArgsPdf,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");

    gifCursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndexUri = gifCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    for (int i = 0; i < gifCursor.getCount(); i++)
        Log.d("gif file uri -> ", gifCursor.getString(columnIndexUri));
}
```

I want to also avoid the third party modules as they would increase the size of the app. You can suggest if there is any module available for this with low size.

I have Tried checking the existance of flags like ANIM, VP8, in image file and it works well but this explicit method is time consuming.

The major issue in this is webp as same extention would be static or animated. This makes difficult me to identify the animated and static type.

Comment: A [semi-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412529/how-do-i-programmatically-check-whether-a-gif-image-is-animated) (in python) goes over some approaches for this, which you could take as an inspiration. More information about your setup (backend server, other libraries e.g. ffmpeg available), and _why_ you want to do this, would help in determining a better solution.

Comment: ffmpeg has many good features and it is heavy in size. Cannot use that for only type checking. It would increase the app size. I am already using React Native which increases the app size :D.

Comment: I tried that magic number checking method and it works but need to extract bytes for each image which causes the little bit delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I maybe found a solution... try using
[ImageDecoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder)

the documentation says

> If the encoded image is an animated GIF or WEBP, decodeDrawable will
> return an AnimatedImageDrawable.

So maybe checking that the result of `ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(source);` is an instance of `AnimatedImageDrawable` should help you figure out if a file is animated or not

such as:

```
ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(cr,uri);
Drawable drawable = ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(source);
  if (drawable instanceof AnimatedImageDrawable) {
      //THE FILE IS ANIMATED
  }else{
      //THE FILE IS STATIC
}
```

or such as

```
private boolean isAnimated(ContentResolver cr,Uri uri){
        ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(cr,uri);

        Drawable drawable = ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(cr,source);
   return drawable instanceof AnimatedImageDrawable;
}
```

EDIT:
for API 28 and before, we should use Movie class

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
  ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(file);
  Drawable drawable = ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(source);
      return drawable instanceof AnimatedImageDrawable;
} else {
  Movie movie = Movie.decodeStream(input);
  return movie != null;
}
```

I hope that helps with your problem