# How to check a jpeg image whether corrupt?

Tags: opencv, corrupt, imread

Here, I use opencv `imread` read the all the image without any problem while it raise out Corrupt Data: xxx extraeous bytes before marker 0xd9 when training with neural networks. How could I get out these corrupt data(just select out, do not need repair or any other operations).

Comment: seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1401527/5008845

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to filter out the corrupt files, you can use a [`try` - `except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) block:

```py
for file in files:
    try:
        img = cv2.imread(file)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks. I means it are normal when using the way you suggested, but it gives the information 'Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment' when in the training process.

Comment: @JianzhongHe Perhaps it's a warning? If so you can make it not appear following the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14463277/13552470

Comment: Yes，it is indeed a warning. Now I resolved it by this anwser https://stackoverflow.com/a/26238635/12371459.